# Firebase orderByChild with equalTo() doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to use .indexOn of firebase on field 'status' which is inside the child of 'BOUGHT_PRODUCT'.

But, when i run following query.

```
db.ref().child('BOUGHT_PRODUCT')
.orderByChild('status')
.equalTo('Service')
.on("value", function (snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
```

I get null snapshots.
Even, Firebase warning of index :
"@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "status" at /BOUGHT_PRODUCT to your security rules for better performance."

Firebase Data:
[image: Firebase Data]

Index firebase:
[image: Index firebase]

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Database queries run against each child under the location where you run them. The field you order/filter on must be at a fixed path under each child. Since you run the query on `/BOUGHT_PRODUCT`, the database searches for `/BOUGHT_PRODUCT/$uid/status`. And since that property doesn't exist, there are no results matching the query.

In other words: your current data structure allows you to query a specific user for the status of their products, but not across all users. If you want to implement that use-case, you will need to create a data model that allows it, e.g. a single top-level list of product statuses.

```
Statuses
  product1: "Service"
  product2: "Service"
  product3: "Something else"
```

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Thanks frank. It makes sense now that why my indexing and queries isn't working